# Aristotle Categories Chapter 2

Tags: aristotle

What exactly is meant by predication and "in a subject"? I have watched 2 lectures and from what I gathered, predication is "what is being said of a subject" and in a subject is "what is contained in a subject".

My problem is that when reading Aristotles examples of predication, it seems as if he describing it as primary and secondary substances, as in "Thus 'man' is predicable of the individual man". I don't understand how the individual man can be said "of" man.

I just can't make head or tails of it, and I've been stuck on this for at least a day now.

Comment: The species in which the things primarily called substances are called secondary substances, as also are the genera of these species. For example, the individual man belongs in a species, man, and animal is a genus of the species; so these—both man and animal—are called secondary substances. Thus the individual man can be said "of" man, or in other words, 'man' is predicable of the individual man...

Comment: Related [Aristotle Categories section 2](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/70046/aristotle-categories-section-2)

Comment: See also the post [Fourfold categories development in Aristotle](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/51963/fourfold-categories-development-in-aristotle)

Comment: And see the post [In what way is Socrates a primary substance?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/27956/in-what-way-is-socrates-a-primary-substance)

Comment: Also SEP's entry [Aristotle’s Categories](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-categories/)